# Excel - Counting number of phone numbers in range

Tags: excel

Cell A2: 5555550000
Cell A3: 5555550003

Trying to find a way to count the number of phone numbers in this range. The cheat way is:

```
=A3-A2+1
```

This would give me "4" because the first phone number actually is a value that needs to be calculated. Such is the case with a range like 5550000-5550099 which is 100 numbers, not 99.

Is there a function in excel that actually does the same thing as my cheat formula? I'm in the mood to learn something. Upon searching the internet, I didn't find anything that could help me in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think there is any need for something easy like that... so: no... also, it is not a cheat-formula: it is the correct way to do it

Comment: so the assumption is that all phone numbers have been assigned?  Also, are you assuming that all area codes are valid?  Using 5535550000 and 5555550000 doesn't mean there are ~2k phone numbers if the area code 554 isn't valid.

Comment: @sous2817 how should excel know if a number exists or not? and not having an order leaves the question, why calc it for a range you allready have values between and not telling???

Comment: @sous2817 Not sure why 553 area code was typed as that is not what I typed. It doesn't matter if it is real. I'm not posting real phone numbers on an online question board. It was an example fake number. In this case, I showed two examples of what TNs look like in a range and how it is calculated. I often have ranges where it is a lot of little ranges that I would like to add up quickly. 5550131-5550252 which is easy to subtract and add +1, but I had hoped there was a feature that I just didn't know about.

Comment: however, to get all natural numbers between and including two natural numbers you can change it to `=ABS(A2-A3)+1` so it doesn't matter which number is the bigger one...

Comment: @DirkReichel  not all things should be automated with a calculation.  My point if, if you take this approach (I'm not saying it's right or wrong) make sure you outline the assumptions you're making. Obviously, we don't know  the whole use case but if you're doing this to generate a "how many people do I have to call", this will give you the maximum possible number of calls you'd have to make.  By no means is it an accurate number of calls.

Comment: If the goal is to learn something today, perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) would shed some light.

Comment: @sous2817 - You know what they say about assumptions. In my job, I have multiple ranges for phone numbers that are required for porting large amounts of numbers. To ensure I can count the exact number of phone numbers in a range, I would like to automate this task because I often have many small and large blocks. 555-0000 - 555-0010, 555-1238 - 1279, etc. I'm currently building a spreadsheet that can do the counting for me and also list the TNs.

Comment: @JS completely understand.  If it were me, I'd do it the way you've outlined above and make note somewhere that "this assumes all numbers in the range are valid numbers"...but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

For many small and large blocks Excel can help. With the lower limit of each in ColumnA and the upper in ColumnB (a repeat of the `A` value where a single number 'range') then summing the two columns (say in Row12) and:

```
=B12-A12+COUNT(A1:B11)/2
```

should give the total. This is barely easier than `B1-A1+1` - very similar to your approach - and then copying down and summing but may have a slight advantage in that it might be used as a template, where if the totals are in a row with high enough number there will always be empty rows available (and the result always in the same cell). The `+1` in the shorter formula would not allow that, though would easily be overcome with:

```
=IF(A1<>0,B1-A1+1,0)
```